# Filter map and return list of keys

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

We have a `Map<String, Student> studentMap`, where `Student` is a class as follows:

```
class Student{
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

We need to return a list of all Ids `eligibleStudents`, where the age > 20.
Why does the following give a compilation error at the `Collectors.toList`:

```
HashMap<String, Student> studentMap = getStudentMap();
eligibleStudents = studentMap .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getValue().getAge() > 20)
        .collect(Collectors.toList(Entry::getKey));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Collectors.toList()` does not take any argument, you need to `map` it first:

```
eligibleStudents = studentMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getValue().getAge() > 20)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

`toList()` collector just creates a container to accumulate elements and takes no arguments. You need to do a mapping before it is collected. Here's how it looks.

```
List<String> eligibleStudents = studentMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getValue().getAge() > 20)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

After `filter`, you are getting a stream of the type `Student`. For each of these students in the filtered stream, you want his/her age. So, you'll have to do a one-to-one mapping b/w a student and his/her age. Use the `map` operator for this as:

```
HashMap<String, Student> studentMap = getStudentMap();
            eligibleStudents = studentMap .entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(a->a.getValue().getAge()>20)
                    .map(a -> a.getKey())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your solution is Collectors.toList() method doesn't take any parameters. see the definition below.

`public static <T> Collector<T,?,List<T>> toList()`

After the **filter** operation you will get the `stream` of `Entry<Id, Student>`.
So you have to transform the `Entry<Id, Student>` to `Id`.
After the **map** operation in below solution you will have the `stream` of `Id`.
Then do the collection of Ids.

```
HashMap<String, Student> studentMap = getStudentMap();
List<Id> eligibleStudentIds = studentMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getValue().getAge()>20)
            .map(a -> a.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would always suggest to try to debug what you are getting after your terminal operations.

There is a feature in Intellij `Alt+Ctrl+V` which will tell you what you are getting on left side after the operation.

**Example**:

When you have the below code :

```
studentMap .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(a -> a.getValue().getAge() > 20)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And when you select it all and press `Alt+Ctrl+V` then you will realize that this code block returns `List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>` ,

So Now you know that your return is not a `List` of String, you now need to winnow other stuffs and only accept further String, For that you will need to use `map`.

As soon as you map like below code snippet:

```
studentMap .entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(a->a.getValue().getAge()>20)
                    .map(a -> a.getKey())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And now when you select the whole code snippet and press `Alt+Ctrl+V` then you will get to know that now you are getting the actual return what you wanted earlier i.e `List<String>`.

Hope it helps you further in coming days of your coding.